# react native pdf View

Tags: android, pdf, reactjs, react-native

Good day mates,

I'm currently having a problem with our project. I'd like to rerender a pdf with fields to contain texts and a signature, are there any ways or solution available to get this?

Please direct me to the right direction. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [react-native-view-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-pdf) package? It's pretty simple and has zero NPM dependencies:

```
import PDFView from 'react-native-view-pdf';

<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <PDFView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    onError={(error) => console.log('onError', error)}
    onLoad={() => console.log('PDF rendered from url')}
    resource="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"
    resourceType="url"
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

Recently i did a similar research for our java-webapp. Those may be useful in your case also:

- You can use [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) to convert your XHTML based template
  into PDF (CSS2.1 supported - you'll be able to render really pretty
  PDFs)
- If HTML and CSS are not your strengths - stick with [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/).
- As an experimental solution - you can try to generate those on
  client-side with [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) (for simplistic stuff this approach may
  do it)

In the end we chose Flying Saucer and we're pretty happy with the results

Answer (score -1):

try this [react-native-pdf-view](https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-pdf-view) on github